# Firebase UI: Solution to receive all keys from a child and use it to receive information from another node and fill it in a Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am searching for a solution to get the data from my child "medication" and use the IDs to receive specific data from the "medication_plan" node and displaying them in a Recyclerview.

DB-Structure:

[image]

At the moment I am using Firebase UI to fill my Recyclerview

```
private DatabaseReference mRef;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Medication,MedicationViewHolder> mAdapter;

List<User> items = new ArrayList<>();

User user = new User();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    setData();
}

private void setData() {
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Medication_plan");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Medication> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Medication>()
            .setQuery(query,Medication.class)
            .build();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Medication, MedicationViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MedicationViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Medication model) {
            final Medication tempmed = new Medication(model.getDr()
                    ,model.getMedicine()
                    ,model.getDate()
                    ,model.getComment());

            holder.mDoctor.setText(model.getDr());
            holder.mMedicine.setText(model.getMedicine());
            holder.mDate.setText(model.getDate());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MedicationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_text_view,viewGroup,false);
            MedicationViewHolder vh = new MedicationViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mAdapter.startListening();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mAdapter.stopListening();
    super.onStop();
}
```

When I use this code I get every medication plan, but I only want the specific plans from the user.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried already? See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated my post with the code but I don't know logic behind it obtaining the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to get your data:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child("R3").child("medication");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            list.add(snap.child("id").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

After that add this code to get the second data info:

```
ArrayList<String> listOfSomething = new ArrayList<String>();
DatabaseReference ref=  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Medication_plan");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (String s: list) {
            listOfSomething.add(dataSnapshot.child("s").child("comment").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

in my example I retrieve the comments. You can change it in whatever you want to retrieve.

Comment: Oh now i see...in the first id you have a digit and in the second you have a String.
Change the first id into "1234"

Comment: Oh yeah I see my mistake, thank you. I tried your code again and it works perfectly but I am still stuck. Now I am having the Ids from the User but I need to fetch specific Information in the Medications_plans with the help of the Ids

Comment: i added an edit for your second question. :) If i helped you a thumps up and the tick button will help me too. Please ask me for whatever you want!

Answer (score 0):

To get only the medicine that corresponde to a specific user, you need to query your database twice. Once to get the medicine ids and second to get the details of your medicines like in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference medicationRef = rootRef.child("User").child("r3").child("medication");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String medicationKey = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference medicationKeyRef = rootRef.child("Medication_plan").child(medicationKey);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Medication medication = ds.getValue(Medication.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, medication.getMedicine());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                }
            };
            medicationKeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
medicationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
Aspirin
Paracetamol
```

Beside that, you'll also should simplify the `User` node like in following schema:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- User
        |
        --- R3
            |
            --- lastname: "Hirsch"
            |
            --- medication
            |      |
            |      --- 1234: true
            |      |
            |      --- assf12: true
            |
            --- name: "Rob"
```

The above code will also work for this structure.

Comment: Sorry I forgot! I tried it recently but it didnt work out for me.

Comment: @HoaBinh Why do you say it didn't work? Do you have an error or what is the behaviour?